# 2-D Analgoue of Pseudosphere

Tags: geometry, ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus

I was reading about the pseudosphere here: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Pseudosphere.html

I was curious if anyone knew what the 2-D analogue of the pseudosphere is?

Thanks!

Comment: First, the pseudosphere is 2D, so you are asking for 1D (or 3D?). Analogue in what sense? The intrinsic curvature? In 1D does not exists.

Comment: The tractrix: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Tractrix.html generates the pseudosphere through revolution. Is that the sense that you mean analogue? A circle is the 2D analogue of the sphere in this sense.

Comment: @Thomas Moore: The pseudosphere is already a  2-D.surface with defined curvature of the surface and lines. For the question "What is 2-D analogue of a sphere"?  what might be your answer? Please make your query more clear. Or by 2-D did you mean flat or plane?

Answer (score 1):

Mathematically the pseudosphere is a 2D surface of constant negative Gaussian curvature. It only looks 3D because of the way it is immersed in 3-space.

There is no concept equivalent to negative curvature for 1D, so the nearest analogy is the ordinary 1-sphere of constant curvature, or circle.